# TYPO3 8.7.9 - Accordion Menu with splitted menu lines

Tags: html, menu, typo3, typoscript

For a mobile navigation I use an accordion menu with the following simple TypoScript:

```
lib.testMenu = HMENU
lib.testMenu {
  entryLevel = 0
  wrap = <div id="mobile_menu">|</div>
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      IFSUB = 1
      IFSUB {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-sub">|</li>
    }

    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  }

   2 < .1
   3 < .1
   3 {
     IFSUB {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-sub">|</li>
    }
  }
  4 < .3
}
```

The first two levels usually have only headlines. The class' has-sub' allows you to open the next level using jquery. On the 3rd and 4th level there are the contents. I therefore need a menu line that contains both the link to the web page at the respective level and a link to open the level below it.
It should look like this:

'link-of-the-current layer |' Arrow' (link to open the layer below).'

```
    <li>link-of-the-current-level</li> 
    <li class="has-sub">' Arrow' (link to open the layer below)' ><ul><li> (...)</li><> (...)</li></ul></li>
```

If there is no lower level, there should be no

```
<li class="has-sub"> (...)</li>.
```

In spite of many attempts, I have unfortunately not come closer to a solution and therefore I am happy about any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood it correctly, the final result should be:

```
<li>
  <a href="">Title of the page</a>
</li>
<li class="has-sub">
  'Arrow'
    <ul>
      <li> (...)</li>
      <li> (...)</li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Am I right?

I think that it should be:

```
lib.mainmenu = HMENU
lib.mainmenu {
  entryLevel = 0
  wrap = <div id="mobile_menu">|</div>
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        expAll = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>      
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first has-sub">|</li>
        }   
    }

   2 < .1
   2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="second">|</li>
   2.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="second has-sub">|</li>
   3 < .1
   3.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="third">|</li>
   3 {
     IFSUB {

        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="third hasarrow">|</li>
        allWrap = |</li><li class="third has-sub">'Arrow'
    }
  }
  4 < .3
  4.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="fourth">|</li>
  4.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="fourth hassub">|</li>
  4.IFSUB.allWrap = |
}
```

Maybe not the cleanest solution :) I guess that some TypoScript expert could do better :)

I have just added some more classes for a better understanding of what level I was printing. Let me know if I have understood it correctly and this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reaction. The generated HTML looks great, excatly what I needed. But I have prolems with jquery for the accordion now. So I have to do more tests.

Comment: After some testing everything is fine. So thanks again,